# Mashup Google maps & photos by Flickr

Tags: javascript, json, mashup

I've some problems with this little script which permits me to create a mashup with google maps and photos by flickr. It creates a simple map from Rome to Milan and after that, it requests ten images from flickr based on geotag. So at the end, it positions every photo like a marker taken from google.

But I can't understand what I've done wrong. Does anybody have some ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Mappa+info</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
body { background:#FFFFFF; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:150%; text-align:center;}
#map { width:100%; height:100%; }
input { width:250px; }
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC0HAM8PI7RMqUiSm444JDehtJOsWBtE_E&sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;
    var latlongp1;
    var latlongp2;

    function initialize() {

        calcRoute();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var myOptions = { 
            zoom:7,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var latlonbounds=map.getBounds();               alert(latlonbounds.getNorthEast());
        latlongp1=latlonbounds.getNorthEast();
        latlongp2=latlonbounds.getSouthWest();


        posizionaFoto();


    }

    function calcRoute() {
            var partenza = "Roma";
            var arrivo = "Milano";
            var request = {
                origin:partenza, 
                destination:arrivo,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
    }

    function posizionaFoto(){

    //richiesta flickr
    var bbox=latlongp1.lat()+","+latlongp1.lng()+","+latlongp2.lat()+","+latlongp2.lon();   
    var apikey="48770d8235b7055d803bd8d913304624";
    var url="http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?"+
            "method=flickr.photos.search"+
            "&format=json"+
            "&per_page=10"+
            "&extras=geo"+
            "&bbox="+bbox+
            "&nojsoncallback=1"+
            "&api_key="+apikey;

    var client =new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("GET",url,true);
    client.send();
    client.onreadystatechange=function(){

                    if((client.readyState==4)&&(client.status==200)){
                        var data=JSON.parse(client.responseText);
                        var photos=data.photos;
                        //creazione marker per foto
                        var photo=photos.photo;
                        var aPhoto;
                        var url;
                        for(var k in photo){
                            aPhoto=photo[k];
                            var markerIcon=new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://farm"+aPhoto.farm+"static.flickr.com/"+aPhoto.server +"/"+aPhoto.id+"_"+aPhoto.secret+"_b.jpg");
                            var latLonphoto=new google.maps.LatLng(aPhoto.latitude,aPhoto.longitude);
                            var markerOptions={
                                map:map,
                                position:latLonphoto,
                                icon:markerIcon                                 
                                };
                            marker=new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
                            }                           
                        }
                    };  
    }

    window.onload = initialize;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

in the line where you set markerIcon there is "."  missing before "static"